# Heroku Push Error: "sprockets-2.0.0.beta.2 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sprockets

I'm tryting to push my RoR 3.1.0.beta1 project up to Heroku from my Git repository using the following command as usual:
`git push heroku master`

But I am getting the following error:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Could not find sprockets-2.0.0.beta.2 in any of the sources
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

My Gemfile has this line:
`gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.2'`

Sprockets version 2.0.0.beta.2 exists because I've been pulling different versions including this version.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: None of the three answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this version has been pulled from Rubygems, only beta.12 and beta.13 are listed:

http://rubygems.org/gems/sprockets

So you'd need to get the [specific beta.2 branch](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/tree/v2.0.0.beta.2) from the repo, as Thariq suggests.

BUT, I'd probably go for one of the versions listed on rubygems - there must be good a reason why they were pulled ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not on rubygems because:

[image]

You need to figure out what source you are getting the gem from and add that to the top of your gem file like so:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.2'
```

`gem "sprockets", "~> 1.0.2"` is on ruby gems. But you will need to find where your versions is specifically hosted such as `http://mysite.org` add that to the top of your `gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you've been pulling from the [Sprockets Git Repo](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). You need to tell your Gemfile where you get a gem that's not in rubygems, so in this case you would use:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.2', :git => 'git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git'
```